# OutputCaching firefox 3.6.12 problem asp mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, firefox, outputcache

On my asp.mvc app I use OutputCaching

```
[HttpGet, OutputCache(Duration=1800, VaryByParam="*", VaryByHeader="Cookie", Location=System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
```

The content is versioned by params and cookie. When I would like new content version I modify cookie:

```
HttpCookie mod = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Get("modify");
        if (mod != null)
            mod.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        else
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("modify", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
```

in action filter (OnActionExecuted)

All browsers except firefox works well after some action is executed cache is refreshed for user. For example action "LogOff" works well in opera, ie but there is a problem in ff. This problem is on my production environment. On integration and devs works perfectly.